# I have a list of users around 3k that I want to delete from IBM Trivoli Identity Manager

Tags: ldap, identity

As the question says above I want to delete 3k users from ITIM but I don’t see any bulk delete users options in ITIM and I don’t know how to progress with this. I thought of writing a python script but I don’t know how to get going with it.

Comment: What in particular are you stuck at?